# Creating an Android "ConnectivityProvider" similar to ContentProvider

Tags: java, android, networking

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible in Android to create a "ConnectivityProvider" component that provides Internet connectivity to existing apps (of type MOBILE) and can be registered inside the framework (similar to a ContentProvider) without modifying the Android Framework and existing apps?

I will draw a diagram:

```
                 ******* WIFI
                 *
 ************    ******* Mobile ***** Cellular (3/4G)
 * Existing ******              *
 *   App    *                   ***** MyConnectivityProvider
 ************
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the diagram nor the question. Internet is already accessible, what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to create another way to access the Internet that does not use conventional interfaces like WiFi or 4G.